I've a sound that work in sf::Music but not in sf::Sound, why?
I'm trying to play a single sound with the C++ SFML lib.
As it's a short sound that I want reuse multiple times I want it to be a sf::Sound and not a sf::Music.
In order to test that I'm trying to make the sound repeating every seconds to test it. The sound itself last less than one second. So there is the code I'm testing :
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow window{};

    sf::SoundBuffer buffer{};
    sf::Sound sound{};
    if (!buffer.loadFromFile("./client/assets/audio/sounds/blaster.wav"))
        std::cerr << "blaster.wav cannot be loaded." << std::endl;
    sound.setBuffer(buffer);

    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point spawnTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    while (window.isOpen()) {
        if (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - spawnTime).count() >= 1) {
            sound.stop();
            sound.play();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

I got the error message "blaster.wav cannot be loaded." and obviously I hear nothing.
But I tried with another file and it work juste fine. You could think, as I did in first time, that the path of my blaster.wav file is wrong or that the blaster.wav file isn't compatible with the SFML at all. But I tried the same manipulation but with sf::Music and it worked. There is the code I tested with the sf::Music :
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow window{};

    sf::Music music;
    if (!music.openFromFile("./client/assets/audio/sounds/blaster.wav"))
        std::cerr << "blaster.wav cannot be loaded." << std::endl;

    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point spawnTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    while (window.isOpen()) {
        if (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - spawnTime).count() >= 1) {
            music.stop();
            music.play();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

But, and if I'm wrong please correct me, using sf::Music this way is not recommended. So I'm insisting trying to work with sf::Sound. So if there is someone that can explain me why this isn't working and maybe how to solve this I would be happy.
PS: The code I'm sharing is an extract of a bigger code so I may have forgot to include a header file. If you find a missing header that block the build, please say it so I can update my question. Thank you in advance for reading until the end.

The notes about MP3 files in sf::InputSoundFile::openFromFile make me think you might want to try WAV, OGG, or FLAC format.  It could be that your MP3 isn't InputSoundFile friendly.
